# Add title and change format to 2 decimals places of msgbox output

Tags: vba, excel

Would need to add a title and change the ouput decimal places (2 decimal) of below code but i am with problems doing it. Can you help? Thanks a lot

```
Sub msgAlert()

MsgBox "First Response Time (hours)= " & _ 
 Worksheets("Parsing").Range("H21").Value & _
 vbCrLf & "Investigation Time (hours)= " & _
 Worksheets("Parsing").Range("I21").Value & _
 Format(dTotalArea, "&#,##0")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a title to a message box, use it like this:

```
Msgbox "My message",,"My title"
```

To get two decimal places, use this format:

```
Format(dTotalArea,"0.00")
```

Use a dot (.) as a decimal separator, even if your regional settings would require using a comma (,).

So your code would look like this:

```
Sub msgAlert()

MsgBox "First Response Time (hours)= " & _ 
 Worksheets("Parsing").Range("H21").Value & _
 vbCrLf & "Investigation Time (hours)= " & _
 Worksheets("Parsing").Range("I21").Value & _
 Format(dTotalArea, "0.00"),,"This is the title"

End Sub
```

Let me know if this works. :)

Comment: thanks ! the title works but the decimal places no. The number uses comma by the way. Thats why I used previously "&#,##0" , but without effect.

Comment: No problem :) In VBA, you always have to use the dot (.) as the decimal separator. In Excel, it will be automatically changed to your system setting.